# Prove the infinite union is not regular

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science, automata, regular-language

Prove $\bigcup _{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is not regular. We know $A_i$ is regular, but how can prove the infinite union is not regular. I think a counter example would work, but I can't think of any. Conceptually, I understand the infinite union can't be regular because you can't map infinity with a *finite* state machine.

A counter example of the infinite intersection not being regular is $0^*1^*-0^i1^i$.

In an attempt to answer my own question: 
{0}, {01}, {0011}, {000111}... are all regular, but the union of all these languages $\{0^i1^i\}$ is clearly not regular. Does that work?

Comment: Provide necessary definitions so we know what "regular" means

Comment: Yes, that’s a fine counterexample.

Comment: @Morgan: See the tags.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I know this wasn't the question, but do you mind explaining the counterexample for infinite intersection (that one was from my book).

Comment: In your infinite intersection example, do you mean $0^*1^* - 0^i0^i$, or $0^*1^* - 0^i1^i$? I know I'm not the Brian you meant ;/

Comment: @BrianO $0^i1^i$. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, it's just that, as it was written, the example would have problems:) Fixed now, good.

Comment: Suppose $L = \bigcap_i (0^*1^* - 0^i1^i)$ is regular. Note that $L = (0^*1^* - \bigcup_i 0^i1^i)$. Its complement must be regular too: $\overline{L} = \overline{0^*1^*} \cup \bigcup_i 0^i1^i$, and then $0^*1^* \cap \overline{L} = \bigcup_i 0^i1^i$ would have to be regular too.

Answer (score 1):

There are only countable DFA's but non countable number of languages, thus there is some countable infinite language which is not regular. Write that language as the union of the singletons of the words in the language